# A wide matrix is full rank but its columns are not linearly dependent as expected. Why?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I have a 2×3  matrix,

\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 4 \\ 2 & 3 & 5 \end{pmatrix}

and its rank from row echelon form is 2 which is also the maximum possible rank for the matrix, i.e., a full rank matrix. This means the matrix has two linearly independent rows and so the set of vectors that the matrix represents is linearly independent.
But a wide matrix should have linearly dependent columns. See, [MathsStackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1197263/why-if-we-have-more-columns-than-rows-can-the-columns-not-be-linearly-independ)

So while one concept is hinting at linear dependency the other concept is hinting at linear independency. Is this a contradiction? Also the three vectors are non-collinear and the span of any two vectors covers the third vector too. Therefore the addition of the third vector does not increases the span, and hence from the increasing span criterion, the set of vectors should be linearly dependent. But I am finding the matrix to be of full rank as explained above.

Comment: The matrix having rank 2 means that there exist 2 linearly independent rows (true) but not 3 such rows (true) and that there exist 2 linearly independent columns (true) but not 3 such columns (also true). So there is no contradiction.

Comment: @ Michael. But the matrix is wide, it should have linearly dependent columns.

Comment: @Vikash The fact that the three columns are linearly dependent does not mean that the same is true for every subcollection of columns.

Comment: @ FormulaWriter. "A wide matrix (a matrix with more columns than rows) has linearly dependent columns." This is written as a standard result in https://tinyurl.com/yxuoxm8k

Comment: The three columns ARE linearly dependent...

Answer (score 1):

If we label the columns $c_1,c_2$ and $c_3$ note that $-2c_1+3c_2-c_3=0$ so they are linearly dependent. However for the rows $r_1$ and $r_2$ there is no scalar $\alpha$ such that $r_1+\alpha r_2=0$ so they are linearly independent. In both cases two of the vectors are sufficient to span the column and row space. In general the row and column space will have dimensions equal to the rank of the matrix.

Comment: @ CyclotomicField. I guess your formula is not valid for the last element in the second row. 2 x 3 - 2  = 4 but the value mentioned is 5.

Comment: @Vikash There is no possible formula for the rows because they're linearly independent. It only works for the columns.

Comment: Your formula does not work for columns too.I guess the matrix is actually linearly independent. And so, the statement, "A wide matrix (a matrix with more columns than rows) has linearly dependent columns.", may not always be valid.

Comment: I get $-2c_1+3c_2-c_3=0$.

Comment: @Angina, you seem correct. you rock!

Comment: @AnginaSeng thanks I'll correct it

Answer (score -1):

The rank corresponds to the dimension of $C(A)$ and $C(A^T)$ that is to the maximum number of independent columns and independent rows. In this case the matrix has $2$ independent rows but columns are only independent in pairs (any pair spans $\mathbb R^2$).

Note that for this other case

\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 4 \\ 2 & 4 & 5 \end{pmatrix}

rank is also $2$ but firs and second colums are multiple one of each other as we can argue from the zero column we obtain by the ERRF.

Comment: I know that. But what about the fact that a wide matrix must have linearly dependent columns. See page 69 of https://tinyurl.com/yxuoxm8k

Comment: @Vikash Since $\mathbb R^2$ is spanned by any pair of independent vectors, any set with more that $2$ vectors can't be a linearly independent set (i.e. a basis). Similarly for the general case  $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @ user agreed! But then the matrix is also full rank. I believe only a rank deficient matrix is linearly dependent.

Comment: So for the given matrix, can i say that it is linearly independent, but the set of Vectors (columns vectors) is linearly dependent?

Comment: @Vikash We define a full rank matrix when it attains the maximum possible value that is $r_{max=}\min(n,m)$. Refer to the definitions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Main_definitions).

Comment: @Vikash We usually don't say "a matrix is linearly independent", we refer to columns and rows for linear independence.

Comment: @ user, the max rank of the matrix is 2. And the rank from the row echelon form can be obtained from here. It comes out to be 2. So it is a full rank matrix.

Comment: @Vikash Yes it is a full rank matrix with linearly independent rows and linearly dependent columns.

Comment: @ user. Thank you. Appreciated.